# How to handle routing related to "required" parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to "require" a parameter-string in a router-URL the *proper* way. That is, I have a `token` parameter that *must* be checked on performing a HTTP POST request so to update user information:

```
my_site_name/user/1?token=12345abcdr
```

I am planning to add a constrain in the `router.rb` file so to "require" that `token`. **Is it advisable? Should I proceed like that? If so, how can I state the related router?**

---

Maybe I could state/use a "named router" passing two parameters this way:

```
confirm_user_url(@user, token)
```

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by token? How would this be different from current_user? It looks similar to an md5 hashed scheme for lost passwords but that scheme exists because one couldn't be current_user

Comment: why not require a POST-token to be set? You could redirect the user to another page if the token is not set before updating the user information in the users_controller. But I'm not sure what you are trying to archive - is it maybe some way of csrf-prevention? If yes, then rails has it implemented by default, see [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf).

Comment: @timpone - Yes, that is: an md5 hashed scheme for lost passwords.

Comment: @markus - No, it isn't a way of csrf-prevention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood, you are trying to make token parameter required when 'performing a HTTP POST request so to update user information' (by the way, should't it be a PUT request, if you are UPDATING?). If so, why not use a custom constraint? In your `routes.rb`:

```
class TokenConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    request.params[:token].present? # or other logic to check token
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  put "/users/:id" => "users#update", :constraints => TokenConstraint.new
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint route parameter is useful to check syntax, no more.

In your case, you can put a **before_filter** in application controller or on a specific controller.

In application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :check_token
.
.
.
def check_token
 .
 .
 if token_valid
   # do this
 else 
   # do this
   return false # to stop further processing by other controllers
 end
end
```

Comment: You may be right, but is there a way to use "named routes" like, for example, `confirm_user_url(@user, token)` that "understands"/"cares" input parameters?

Comment: Not sure to understand the problem. You have acess to token with params[:token] and to user with params[:user] so I presume you perfom the tests you need.

Comment: I think @AlainBeauvois wants the *URL Constructor* to work. In other words, that the URL constructor accepts takes his argument "token" and makes it accessible to the controller in the form params[:token].